# Facebook SDK landscape sign in Activity for Android?

Tags: android, facebook

I've already implemented the Facebook SDK and the functionality works in my Android app, however, I am just wondering how to make it so that the "login with facebook" popup activity doesn't go into portrait mode, but is instead fixed in landscape?

I've already tried putting the ScreenOrientation to landscape, but that doesn't do a thing:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same issue in tab application, after adding below solution it is working fine
@pizzae: please add the below attributes in Android

> ```
> android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
> ```

to com.facebook.FacebookActivity and com.facebook.CustomTabActivity activities

example

```
<activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation" />


    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: this is not working for me.